# Constraining sequential method calls from the interface of initial parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a runtime API that also acts like a type-assert, in that both components passed must be generic over the same shape.

This keeps failing with an error like this which makes sense:

```
Argument of type 'typeof A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<any>'.
  Property '[S]' is missing in type 'typeof A' but required in type 'Component<any>'.
```

But I'm not really sure how to achieve the thing I'm looking for.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=46&ssc=51&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwKYA8xIMYwCoE90DyAZgL5xFQQhwDkq6WAtDPkjQNwBQnAJpgDYBDKEjgYIAOwDO8AMoAuOAFcJwAI5LRU3CABGEfl14DhojEKlS4AYSqQJSCTAA8sgHyJOcOH3Om4YFDAAG6CMKIA2rIAuoqyXCTcLOhwAJISREhQssAA5hJhSiLO2B4AvHDYcKjhEjxWtuCSji7AGVlwOfmFIh4A-J15BTBFoooOwVlGvkIiYhZWAILVKLX1NnbNTs4IXnAFIEiKMkESuVzegrlH+0p6U5wkHggk0yZzfpZwAEIraw2bBzbXbeEDAKQgMIYAAWihgUE0j2eiU4RBUWGAknIlBA2Gh4JKf0c60a9hazkEElwbjcAAo8eDSVsYIpsABKTzeEQjKASTneOAwCB4sLOABKRLqAKaQJc6Uy2SGPSQJRpdJFMCZssUYo5IIFXKQPL5+oN3gA7sAYNCxSoYKAkNgkDJaYLnTAAHKCQ7HeFtXJ6vZmgXAIhwWmWuoQc0AOn4EAwYUxEhjUiQwhhMba5iUfCktPCMi9hzZgeDwe5RT5Gq1LQu5e8KIbhuNlXxUlrTnrwcSPaDcF7A8e3AA9CO4AAFSjoKD8XBwNoKqScZKiRZdOAVeVZLrDUbORZuLhjuCLfhSCABadZGBzhftKDL1c-Ddbh+75XOb5H0fjhlWa1RGfCAw10JBoUEYJMSgNIaGoeMIAAa39choE4ehMBwVhiAPLo6TZGMhQAUQ0QR+DwQgiFpb4ujZbhOBPf8fAgZ19ggeBzWgRC4H4YBENEDCsAopBiFRHF-1pRYCKFDVqIIy1rVtJwHSdF04NwRhdGYd0aDZIA)

```
import {expectTypeOf} from 'expect-type';

declare const S: unique symbol;

declare class Component<S> {
  declare private [S]: S;
}

type InferSignature<T> = T extends Component<infer Signature> ? Signature : never;

declare class A extends Component<{
  name: string;
  age: number;
}> {};

declare class B extends Component<{
  mismatch: true
}> {}

function fromThis<T extends Component<any>>(ThisComponent: T) {
  return {
    toThat<R extends Component<InferSignature<T>>>(ThatComponent: R) {
      return {
        withRuntimeTest( testName: string) {
          if (window.location.search.includes(testName)) {
            return ThatComponent;
          }

          return ThisComponent;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Properly infers
type ASig = InferSignature<A>;
// Also propertly infers
type BSig = InferSignature<B>;

// This the type of behavior I'm looking for
expectTypeOf<ASig>().toEqualTypeOf(BSig)


// This does not work like expectTypeOf
fromThis(A).toThat(B).withRuntimeTest('my-b-test')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.

```
declare const S: unique symbol;

declare class Component<S> {
  declare private [S]: S;
}

declare class A extends Component<{
  name: string;
  age: number;
}> {};

declare class B extends Component<{
  mismatch: true
}> {}

type Ctor<T> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
type ComponentCtor =  Ctor<Component<any>>;

function fromThis<T extends ComponentCtor>(ThisComponent: T) {
  return {
    toThat
    (ThatComponent: Ctor<InstanceType<T>>) {
      return {
        withRuntimeTest(testName: string) {
          if (window.location.search.includes(testName)) {
            return ThatComponent;
          }

          return ThisComponent;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fromThis(A).toThat(B).withRuntimeTest('my-b-test')
```